# Call Restlet from external suitelet with authentications

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Can We call Restlet From External Suitelet with NLAuth or any auth.Kindly post some sample please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest way to do a GET to a RESTlet:

```
var headers = {};
headers["Authorization"] = 'NLAuth nlauth_account=TSTDRVXXXXX, nlauth_email=xxx@xxx.com, nlauth_signature=XXXXXXX, nlauth_role=3';
headers["contentType"] = 'application/json';

var url = 'https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=xxxx&deploy=xxx';

var response = nlapiRequestURL(url, null, headers);
```